# Where to place counter variable in python loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, scope, counter

What disallows me from putting the `evenCounter` or 'oddCounter' variables inside the *for loop* or *if statement*? How does the loop know where the counters are if they are out of the loop's scope?

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
evenCounter = 0
oddCounter = 0

for i in list1:
  if i%2 == 0:
    evenCounter += 1
  else:
    oddCounter += 1

print(evenCounter)
print(oddCounter)
```

if this question is a duplicate, dont hesitate to flag it as such

Comment: Huh? You're asking why you can't put the assignment `evenCounter = 0` inside the loop?

Comment: Please clarify: you *do* have the variables inside both the `for` loop and the `if` statement.  Do you mean the `print` statements or the initial assignments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `counter` is in the loop, it keeps restarting as you iterate through your sequence. The `loopCounter` below is getting added in the `if-else` loop but keeps resetting to zero at every iteration, in this example, you can see it with `print`

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
evenCounter = 0
oddCounter = 0

for i in list1:
    loopCounter = 0
    print(loopCounter)

    if i%2 == 0:
        evenCounter += 1
        loopCounter += 1
    else:
        oddCounter += 1
        loopCounter += 1

print(evenCounter)
print(oddCounter)
```